# hibernate query giving an inccorect result list

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, hql

this is the method Dao layer List,

```
public List<PortfolioMemberView> getPortfolioMemberViewByPid(Integer pid){
    //check the portfolioId value in console
    System.out.print(pid);
    try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String sql = "from PortfolioMemberView pv where pv.portfolioId = ?0";
        Query query = session.createQuery(sql).setParameter(0, pid);
        List<PortfolioMemberView> pmvl = query.list();
        //check the result list by assetCode in console
        for(PortfolioMemberView pv: pmvl){
            System.out.print(pv.getAssetCode());
        }
        return pmvl;
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.info("操作失败："  + e.getMessage() + ", " +e.getCause());
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
```

I have a view(That I create) PortfolioMemberView in my database
and it has the following data

[inmage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZNRZ.png)

when I involke the method, the console print following result.

```
2
Hibernate: select portfoliom0_.portfolioId as portfoli1_8_, 
portfoliom0_.assetId as assetId2_8_, portfoliom0_.accountType as accountT3_8_, portfoliom0_.assetCode as assetCod4_8_, portfoliom0_.assetLabel as assetLab5_8_, portfoliom0_.value_ as value_6_8_, portfoliom0_.annualReturn as annualRe7_8_, portfoliom0_.returnRate as returnRa8_8_ from PortfolioMemberView portfoliom0_ where portfoliom0_.portfolioId=?
CMPROP0121CMPROP0121CMPROP0121CMPROP0121CMPROP0121
```

The expected result should be CMPROP0121kckbGYck, because when portfolioId = 2, the assetCode of three object in the resulting list shoud be CMPROP0121，kckb，GYck.

I also copy the query hibenate generated and run it at mysql database, and the result is correct.

```
    Hibernate: select portfoliom0_.portfolioId as portfoli1_8_, 
portfoliom0_.assetId as assetId2_8_, portfoliom0_.accountType as accountT3_8_, portfoliom0_.assetCode as assetCod4_8_, portfoliom0_.assetLabel as assetLab5_8_, portfoliom0_.value_ as value_6_8_, portfoliom0_.annualReturn as annualRe7_8_, portfoliom0_.returnRate as returnRa8_8_ from PortfolioMemberView portfoliom0_ where portfoliom0_.portfolioId=?
```

not sure what's wrong, pls help!!!

Comment: String sql = "from PortfolioMemberView pv where pv.portfolioId = ?"; Try removing the ?0 on the query. Just use ?

Comment: it gives me an Exception, legacy way...                    ：org.hibernate.QueryException: Legacy-style query parameters (`?`) are no longer supported; use JPA-style ordinal parameters (e.g., `?1`) instead : from pojoView.PortfolioMemberView pv where pv.portfolioId=? [from pojoView.PortfolioMemberView pv where pv.portfolioId=?], org.hibernate.QueryException: Legacy-style query parameters (`?`) are no longer supported; use JPA-style ordinal parameters (e.g., `?1`) instead : from pojoView.PortfolioMemberView pv where pv.portfolioId=? [from pojoView.PortfolioMemberView pv where pv.portfolioId=?]

Comment: PLease just so i undestand the issue, try this form of Binding 

 `String sql = "from PortfolioMemberView pv where pv.portfolioId = :pid";
 Query query = session.createQuery(sql).setParameter("pid", pid);`

Comment: i just tried，it print the same incorrect answer

Comment: What are the results you are getting from the database?

Comment: http://i1.bvimg.com/669971/0ec4711e00c434e0.jpg

Comment: That should the correct results, check you database in the image you shared.

Comment: yes， it is correct when I run it in database. not correct with the method though. I cannot see what is wrong with my method

Comment: what do you get with the method? That is what i need

Comment: I get, CMPROP0121CMPROP0121CMPROP0121CMPROP0121CMPROP0121, 5 CMPROP0121(assetCode), it suppose to print 5 different assetCodes, but it prints the first assetCode for five times instead .

Comment: in the method there is a print method that traverse the result list(a list of PortfolioMemberView Object). The result prints on the console didn't print the assetCode from all five object, instead it print the assetCode from the first Object for five times

Answer (score 0):

I mapped portfolioId as primary Id, and primary Id cannot be duplicated. but obviously the primary key portfolioId is duplicated. I make aother primary key portfolioMemberId, and the problem solved